# Did a building supervisor in Spain get fined for not showing up to work for six years, unnoticed?

Tags: work, employment, spain

In this [2016 Huffington Post article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/man-skipped-work-for-6-years_us_56c1d32ae4b0b40245c72512), it says:

> For six years, a building supervisor in Spain quietly collected a $41,500 salary from his local government without showing up for work.
>
> And he would have gotten away with it too if it wasn’t for him getting an award for his 20 years of loyal service.
>
> Joaquín García, 69, was recently fined $30,000 for the extended paid vacation from a water treatment plant in Cádiz -- the maximum penalty government officials could deliver, the BBC reported.

Is it true nobody noticed him not working for 6 years?

Comment: Why do you doubt it, and what would you consider proof? The referenced El Mundo article says effectively the same stuff as the one you linked, and [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Mundo_(Spain)) El Mundo is one of the three Spanish newspapers of record. Could it have been intentional? Of course, his brother-in-law is a politician. Was it intentional? Who knows. I've definitely worked at places where everyone would file a missing overseer under Someone Else's Problem and move on with their days, so I think this sorta stuff is small potatoes for any investigative journalist

Comment: There is a lawsuit. I doubt the spanish legal system don't have a search function. I know zero of spanish, though.

Comment: Similar thing happened in the US. If I'm not mistaken in New York

Answer (score 4):

**Not only YES, but Super Yes**

The public worker, named Joaquín García, has "not been working" for 14 years for the public administration in Cadiz. His job was a quiet one, as his department ( public infraestructure and services) is an overexpanded one with too many engineering supervisors to notice ( words of his direct boss). 
Given that, every morning since his prior boss started a mobbing strategy on him, he came in, checked with the checking machine, went home, came back to breakfast with the coworkers, and then checked out at exit time.

[El Mundo, important spanish newspaper](http://www.elmundo.es/andalucia/2016/02/10/56bb61b8e2704e90628b45c8.html)

[The Spanish Economist](http://ecodiario.eleconomista.es/politica/noticias/7344516/02/16/Un-funcionario-de-Cadiz-pasa-seis-anos-sin-ir-trabajar-pero-cobrando-y-ahora-pide-clemencia-al-Kichi.html)